# use ternary operator to get value of nullable bool in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a one-liner to do this?

`string to = someNullableBool ? "value1" : "value2";`

Currently getting "cannot implicitly convert bool? to bool"... Does the `??` operator come into play here? Or is that only when assigning to a bool?

Basically, if `someNullableBool` is null or false, that should be treated as false.

Comment: `someNullableBool == true ? "value1" : "value2";` ?

Comment: `(someNullableBool ?? false ) ? "value1" : "value2";`

Comment: `someNullableBool.GetValueOrDefault() ? "a" : " b";`

Comment: performance wise, `someNullableBool.GetValueOrDefault() ? "value1" : "value2"` may be preferable (it avoids an `if` / branch), but it is uglier :)

Comment: string to = someNullableBool.HasValue ? "value1" : "value2";

Comment: @Steve - that is wrong for the same reason [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46777944/1260204) is wrong.

Comment: Can you explain if you want to get the value of the boolean variable or a string if the variable is null and another string if the variable is not null?

Comment: `switch(someNullableBool){ case true: to = "value1"; break; default: to = "value2"; break; }` I know you all want to downvote this comment :))))

Comment: @Steve - good point. The OP should clarify. I think most of us were making the assumption based on the title of the post and assumed the word "value" would mean `false` if it was `null` and treat the rest of the LoC as if it were a regular `bool`.

Comment: this one has much better performance :D, `to = (bool)someNullableBool.GetType().GetProperty("HasValue").GetValue(someNullableBool, null) ? (bool)someNullableBool.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(someNullableBool, null) ? "value1" : "value2"  : "value2";`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Most useful content on the entire page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how you want `someNullableBool` to be interpreted if it's null.

If you want `null` to be treated like either `true` or `false`, you can say `(someNullableBool ?? valueIfNull)` to treat it like one or the other.

If `null` has to be handled specially, then you'll need to check `someNullableBool.HasValue` and handle the case where it's null. Once you've done that, the case for `true` and `false` can be handled as above.

If the value should never be null, ideally it shouldn't be a nullable in the first place. :P  But if that's out of your control, you might want to cast to `bool` or use the nullable's `Value` property to make that expectation explicit, and to fail if ever it doesn't hold.

Comment: `you can simply cast to bool` That will result in it *throwing* if it's null, not being treated as `false` (which may be desirable, for the record, if the value shouldn't actually ever be `null`).  See the comments under the question (or just Google) for a million ways to convert a `bool?` to a `bool` where `null` should be treated as `false`.

Comment: @Servy: Ah...looks like i was looking at the wrong conversion. :P Edited.

Answer (score 9):

I would use the following it makes sure that you have a value and that the value is true. It is more readable but not the most performant solution.

```
string to = (someNullableBool.HasValue && someNullableBool.Value) ? "value1" : "value2";
```